# ETPS/" Elantech Touchpad fails detecting single finger

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

I have a new laptop with an "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad".

A single finger is only detected, if it is held in such a way that a big area touches the pad. If one touches the pad only with the fingertip, it wil not be detected, both for clicking and for moving the pointer.

Strangley, two-finger gestures are detected even if the pad is only touched with the fingertips.

On [ubuntuusers.de](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Startseite) I [found](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/touchpad#Identifikation) that Elantech touchpads require to reload the psmouse-module by:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

If I do this, one finger finally gets detected as it should, but all two or more finger gestures stop working. Also

```
grep -B 5 mouse /proc/bus/input/devices
```

tells that the touchpad now is identified as a mouse, while before the changes it was identified correctly as `ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad`.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=133950) is a small explanation on how to set the sensibility of the touchpad.

Set the values for *FingerLow* and *FingerHigh* to `15` and `20`. Original value seemed to be `25` and `30`.

```
synclient FingerLow=15
synclient FingerHigh=20
```

Answer (score 1):

I have submitted a [patch](http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg-devel/2012-March/029602.html) to `xf86-input-synaptics` today; you can see the letter for details.

Basically, it boils down to setting `FingerLow=1 FingerHigh=1` as defaults, as that are the only sensible values for Elantech touchpads.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get all touchpad gestures working by installing the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-multitouch
```

Apparently, this package is not installed by default. No need to change the sensitive of any gesture. Ubuntu 14.04, running on Asus N550JK, with the following touchpad:

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -i pad
N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
```